# How to iterating google pages using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to scrape google search data using Selenium and I can able to get all data as well but at the end when Page is end I can see an error.

```
line 23, in <module>
    next_page = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Next')

 line 428, in find_element_by_link_text
    return self.find_element(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value=link_text)
```

Here is my code and I get this error after successfully collected all data.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep


driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=florida+time+now')

driver.find_element_by_link_text('Change to English').click()
sleep(2)

print(driver.current_url)
print(driver.title)


while True:
    titles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="LC20lb DKV0Md"]')
    for title in titles:
        link_title = title.find_element_by_xpath('.//span').text
        print(link_title)

    sleep(3)
    next_page = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Next')
    if next_page:
        next_page.click()
    else:
        break


sleep(2)
driver.close()
```

Comment: Next - is a <span>, not a link. maybe it could be a reason of your error?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @DmytroHuz the data or title inside the <span> tag. So to get the title I've to access span tag :)

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_link_text('Change to English').click()` i don't see Change to English anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If element not present it will throw error. what you could do check the length of the element using `driver.find_elements_by_link_text('Next')` which will returns `list` of elements.Check length if more than 0 then **click** else **break**.

```
    next_page = driver.find_elements_by_link_text('Next')
    if len(next_page)>0:
        next_page[0].click()
    else:
        break
```